# Check if numeral within bounds in one statement

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to check if a number x is greater than a number a and less than a number b, without specifying x twice?

I can do this:

```rb
x = 4
a = 1
b = 10
x > a && x < b
```

...but is there a way to do something like this:

```rb
# not valid ruby, is there another way?
a < x < b
```

Comment: Why? Something like `Range#include?` is longer, less performant, and uses more resources. I'm not even sure it's more readable.

Comment: (Bored; checked w/ ruby-prof. It's incrementally worse than I originally thought.)

Comment: That largely depends on the cleverness of the compiler. I wouldn't be surprised if TruffleRuby were able to to compile both the OP's version and Jan Vitek's version into whatever the current CPU's variant of `LOAD_CONSTANT true` is.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Definitely, if the bounds are known at compile time.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming the exact code snippet by the OP. But even in the generic case, where you hide it behind a method call and don't supply constant input, TruffleRuby should be able to specialize an integer and float version of the `Range#include?` method that is equivalent to what GCC or Clang would produce for a C implementation of the OP's code. TruffleRuby really has some astonishing tricks up its sleeve. I've seen it fold entire programs using several dynamic Ruby features into a compile-time constant.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's pretty great (as is GraalVM in general, really). Still need to try running work apps under it for the threading and C lib bits. Now I want to do that instead of today's work :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This does not answer the question exactly, please read the Edit part of the answer.*

Tested this to work for `x` being an Integer and a Float.

```
(a..b).include? x
```

Edit:
As @spickermann pointed out in comments the original question excludes the beginning and the end of the interval.

To exclude the end is easy, this is what `...` is for. Therefore

```rb
(a...b).include? x  # is the same as `a <= x && x < b`
```

To exclude the start of the interval is not that easy. One could use `next_float`:

```rb
(a.to_f.next_float...b).include? x
```

However even the `(a...b)` is something I would not use because it is not so common literal and in my opinion decreases readability of the code. With `a.to_f.next_float` we are making some really awkward code that may work for Integers and Floats but I would be afraid of other Numeric data types.

Unless someone brings completely different approach I would stick with `x > a && x < b`

Comment: that's perfect, ty. i'll accept as answer once the SO timer allows me

Comment: Actually, this behaves differently than the requirement from the question. The question was about: `a < x && x < b` but this does `a <= x && x <= b`.

Comment: good points and agree, ty for edit